# Express.js partial: Pressing 'back' in browser

Tags: http, node.js, backbone.js, xmlhttprequest, express

My tech stack: Node.js, express.js, backbone.js.

My web app is a two page app (you can hit two express routes to get fully rendered pages). Let's call them page A and page B. When I load page A and click on a link to load page B and then I press the back button, I only get a partially rendered page A (the part of the page that I can also deliver as an express.js partial with res.partial (not partial() within a template) via XHR).

From what I've debugged so far, pressing back in the browser doesn't hit an express route. When I inspect what Javascript is loaded there are no resources loaded. I was thinking I could do some debugging with the fronend routes (I'm using Backbone.js), but all I see is the partial HTML loaded on page A with no CSS styling and no JS resources.

Any direction on how to debug this issue?

Comment: This might be because of hash tags or pushstate can you post your backbone router code?

Comment: Thx, this was indeed a hashtab/pushstate issue.